# Android: What can cause GPS Provider status to go to "TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE" / "OUT_OF_SERVICE"?

Tags: android, gps, locationlistener

What are the reasons of GPS provider reports "TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE" and/or "OUT_OF_SERVICE" in onStatusChanged listener?